# UITableView reposition when keyboard shows, using constraints

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation, constraints, autolayout

Seem to got into a state adopting autolayout constraints.

'Simply', I have a view with a container view within it (same size as main view) and a further UITableView within this, as per the image.[image]

When a cell is selected in the table, I show the keyboard and move the container view's lower constraint up by the height of the keyboard. (The lower constraint is connected via IBOutlet). The table moves with it as it is constrained.

```
-(void)scrollInputUp:(NSInteger)height duration:(NSTimeInterval)animationDuration
{
    self.keyboardHeight.constant = -height;
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

   NSIndexPath *currentIndexPath = myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow;
   [myTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:currentIndexPath     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
}
```

I also scroll my selected row into position. This works well and appears to be a 'standard' way of doing this with constraints. self.keyboardHeight is my lower constraint and all other constraints are fixed. I then have my reduced-size table.

My problem arises when I dismiss the keyboard as below...

```
-(void)scrollInputDown:(NSTimeInterval)animationDuration
{
     [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    self.keyboardHeight.constant = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

(The five second animation is so I can see what happens!)

This is hard to explain, but if the table view is scrolled up to the last row when the keyboard is showing and then the keyboard dismissed, the tableview 'jumps upwards' and the lower rows almost disappear under the nav-bar. The the whole thing gently scrolls down into position. It's as if the tableview becomes full-size but is of course off-screen then it animates down to fit the view in the correct place.

I hope I have described that sufficiently.  It's not easy to describe animations but under springs and struts, I can smoothly animate the table back to original size AND position. Done at normal animation speeds, this problem causes a flicker which is 'just' acceptable but I would rather fix this issue if anyone can help? I'm pulling my hair out!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can handle all resizing automatically by using the free Sensible TableView framework. Saves me tons of time every day.

Comment: Thanks and maybe so. I may even look at it. But I like to understand my problem, so am looking for help.